# Does positivity of the integral implies positivity of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f\colon [0,T]\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)<\infty$ and let $\int\limits_0^tf(x)dx>0$ for every $t\in(0,T)$. Does it imply that there exists $t_0$ such that  $f$ is positive for $x\in(0,t_0)$?
In general I think that it is not true but maybe the assumption of existence of the derivative of $f$ at zero will help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your claim does not hold, even if $f'(0)$ exists.

As a counterexample, consider the case in which

$$
\int_0^t f(x) \,dx = t^4 \cdot (2 - \sin(1/t)) > 0
$$

for $t> 0$, i.e. (calculate the derivative of the above)

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) & = & 4x^3 \cdot (2 - \sin(1/x)) + x^2 \cdot \cos(1/x) \\
     & = & x^2 [4x \cdot (2 - \sin(1/x)) + \cos(1/x)].  
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

and $f(0) := 0$.

Then $f'(0) = 0$ exists, but using the second formula above, it is easy to see that $f(t) > 0$ does not hold on any intervall $(0,t_0)$ (because $\cos(1/x)$ assumes all values from $[-1,1]$ on any intervall $(0,t_0)$ and the first term in the brackets vanishes for $x$ small enough because of the factor $4x$).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something, but is $f(x)$ continuous at $0$.

Comment: Very good counterexample. +1

Comment: Thanks, great example, but I think that the derivative of $f$ at zero does not exist since $f'(x)=24x^2+6x\cos \frac 1x+(1-12x^2)\sin \frac 1x$? And may I ask, do You know some quite general assumption for $f$ under which something like that will hold?

Comment: The derivative at zero exists (but is not continuous), because $|f(x)| \leq C \cdot x^2$, so that $|\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}| \leq C \cdot |h| \rightarrow 0$ for $h\rightarrow 0$. This is analogous to the example $f(x) = x^2 \cdot \sin(1/x)$ for a function that is differentiable but not continuously differentiable. For the other question, I am not sure. I wanted to prove your claim and by trying, I came up with the example above. The assumption $f'(0) \neq 0$ would suffice, but that is almost trivial.

Comment: @PhoemueX Under the typical definition of the differentiability, $f(x)$ can't have a derivative at a point where $f(x)$ itself is not defined. I assume you mean to define $f(0) = 0$? In which case, $f'(0) = 0$?

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned that somewhere. Indeed, $f(0)=0$ is the (unique) continuous, differentiable extension. I edited the post accordingly.